# jQuery Pages not reading Global Variable (If logged In)?

Tags: variables, jquery, global-variables

I am trying to set up a global variable that will be read across all pages so the page knows one is logged in.  Once one logs in they are re-directed to a `/myaccount.asp` page. I have put the following code on there:

```
var $loggedIn = 1;
```

Now on ALL my pages I have the following code:

```
    var $loggedIn;

    $(document).ready(function () {     
    if ($loggedIn == 1) {
        alert("You are logged In!")
    } else {
        alert("Not Logged In Yet!")
    }});
```

Of course the above ONLY works on the `/myaccount.asp` page, otherwise it shows the alert "Not Logged In Yet!" on other pages.  Is there a way to set a variable so it reads globally, I'm doing something simply wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript variables do not stay constant across page refreshes. As soon as you move on to a new page or refresh the page you're on, everything in Javascript gets refreshed and wiped out. You will need to assign your value as a query parameter (GET) in your URL, or better yet, look into creating cookies.

Comment: Ok I could possibly do that.  Something like this: `var cookLog = $.cookie('logged_in'), ref, { expires: 1});`

Comment: Exactly, and that will stay in tact across multiple pages until you decide to remove it. If you haven't already, the jQuery cookies plugin can be found at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie